# Can't get ngPlural to work Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to get ngPlural to work using Angular version 4.0.3 as stated in the api: https://angular.io/api/common/NgPlural

```
<some-element [ngPlural]="value">
  <ng-template ngPluralCase="=0">there is nothing</ng-template>
  <ng-template ngPluralCase="=1">there is one</ng-template>
  <ng-template ngPluralCase="few">there are a few</ng-template>
</some-element>
```

When I use [ngPlural] I get the error `No provider TemplateRef!` for Template ref. If I remove it and use *ngPlural I also get an error for
`No provider for NgPlural!`

I don't think I need to add this as a provider as it's from the Angular Common Library like *ngIf and *ngFor and they work after connecting the commons library.

Are the docs up to date with v4.0.3?
How can I get this to work in my template?

### Update:

I have added a plunker to showcase this problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/SQwRWjVEJjpQMVkWO1G4?p=preview

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker?

Comment: @yurzui, here is the plunker for it: plnkr.co/edit/SQwRWjVEJjpQMVkWO1G4?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expanded form like:

```html
<div [ngPlural]="value" class="testParent">
   <ng-template ngPluralCase="=0">
      <square class="testBox1"></square>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template ngPluralCase="=1">
     111
   </ng-template>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/O8bEFzoo9Jm1WrXGxeiQ?p=preview)**

or short form:

```html
{ value, plural, =0 {<square class="testBox1"></square>} =1 {111} }
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uu2dfewFnW1xB3Q4iEQ5?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for this Yurzui.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ngPluralCase=""  with an ng-template.

Try this:

```
 <square class="testBox1" [ngPlural]="value">
          <ng-template ngPluralCase="=0">case 0</ng-template>
      </square>
```